# pg-promise: Pass a function as parameter to func()

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise

I am using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) to access our postgres database. I want to call a stored proc `foo(geom)` that accepts a geometry datatype (PostGIS). I only have lats/lngs to start with though, so I want to convert them using postGIS.

This looks like this:

```
db.func('foo', 'ST_MakePoint(' + location.lat + ', ' + location.lng + ')')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(bar);
  });
```

I get an error now, complaining that I have an invalid geometry (the conversion does not happen). I am sure the `ST_MakePoint` works for the values I have. I guess it interprets it as a string and not as a function call when executed on the db.

How should I pass this parameter to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)

Unlike regular query formatting with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), where you specify your formatting template through the formatting variables, you skip that when using methods [func](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#func) and [proc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc), and so they are implied from the type of values.

The most elegant solution is to use the [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting) supported by the library, which allows you to override any data type and provide your own formatting.

You can introduce your own class `Point` like this:

```
function Point(lat, lng) {
    this.lat = +lat;
    this.lng = +lng;
    this.rawType = true; /* use as raw/unescaped value */
    this.toPostgres = p => {
        return 'ST_MakePoint(' + p.lat + ',' + p.lng + ')';
    };
}
```

Then you can pass it in as a regular value:

```
const p = new Point(1, 2);

db.func('foo', [p]).then(...)
```

Alternatively, you can execute your query directly. Not to overvalue method [func](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#func), which simply executes `SELECT * FROM foo`, so you can do:

```
const p = 'ST_MakePoint(' + lat + ',' + lng + ')';

db.any('SELECT * FROM foo($1:raw)', p).then(...)
```

`:raw` - injects the raw/unescaped value.

P.S. In future, rather than guessing what [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) executes, try [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor)  instead, or at least handle [event `query`](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query).

**UPDATE: 29/04/2018**

Updated the syntax for [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting) to adhere to the latest supported by [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

And the shortest syntax for wrapping up a point:

```
const point = (lat, lng) => ({
    toPostgres: ()=> pgp.as.format('ST_MakePoint($1, $2)', [lat, lng]),
    rawType: true
});
```

So you can pass it in simply as:

```
db.func('foo', point(1, 2))
```